# Expand last child of DockPanel to fill the remainder of a form that a user resizes

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm having an issue getting the last child of a WPF form to expand with the form as a user re-sizes it.  The last element is the last of a few docked dockpanels (nested dockpanels).  My understanding of dockpanels is the last added element that isn't docked will expand to fill the remainder of the space provided.  However, I'm unable to get that behavior, whether it be through using the wrong controls or some error in my XAML that I'm not seeing; any help would be appreciated.

Keep in mind, I'm kinda new at XAML and WPF so my terminology and use of controls may be a bit crude.

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl Margin="1">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Height="Auto">
                <Expander Header="Client Details" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" IsExpanded="True" Background="#FFC9C9B9" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="3">
                            <Label Content="Client Name:" Padding="3"/>
                            <TextBox Padding="3"/>
                            <Label Content="SPA Number:" Padding="3"/>
                            <TextBox Padding="3"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="3">
                            <Label Content="Session ID:" Padding="3"/>
                            <TextBox Padding="3"/>
                            <Label Content="Agent Name:" Padding="3"/>
                            <TextBox Padding="3"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Expander>
                <DockPanel Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="DarkGray">
                    <Button Content="Copy" Margin="2" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Padding="3"/>
                    <Button Content="New Session" Padding="3" Margin="2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Label Content="Session ID:" Padding="3" Margin="2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <ComboBox Padding="3"/>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Margin="5" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <Label Content="Session ID:"/>
                    <TextBox MinWidth="60" Padding="3"/>
                    <Label Content="Session Type:"/>
                    <ComboBox Padding="3"/>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Margin="5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Label Content="Problem:" MinWidth="60"/>
                    <RichTextBox Padding="3" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="100" MinHeight="80"/>
                </DockPanel>
                **<DockPanel Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="AliceBlue">
                    <Label Content="Notes:" MinWidth="60"/>
                    <RichTextBox Padding="3" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="400" MinHeight="200"/>
                </DockPanel>**
            </DockPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

The very last DockPanel in this list of nested DockPanels (surrounded by **) is what I'm trying to get to fill the space of the form as it's re-sized vertically however, it's not re-sizing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `VerticalAlignment="Top"` from that last DockPanel. That will jump back to stretch, making it fill the remaining space (up to 400 as MaxHeight).

Comment: Well, that did it.  Out of curiosity, why would the alignment of the contained controls have that affect?  Isn't it simply making sure that those controls contained are aligned to the top of the dockpanel?

Comment: If it's anything else than stretch, it will fit to it's minimum size content. This makes sense, since stretch is simply not aligning at all, but just filling up everything that is remaining (if the parent allows this) :)